# Dynamically creating ComboBox items, filling them with data, and naming them?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to detect how many files are in a directory, then use that number to add the same number of items to a ComboBox. But when I create the items, how do I give each item an individual name? The 'Add' only gives the item its content, but I want to give it an x:Name. This is what I have so far:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\CIC=true.txt"))
    {
        int FileAmount = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA").Length;

        for (int i = 1; i < FileAmount + 1; i++)
        {
            ComboBox.Items.Add();
        }
    }

    File.Create(@"C:\_Kooper Young FBLA\CIC=true.txt");
}
```

Comment: What do you want to show in the ComboBox? The file name? And why a ComboBox? Do you want to select one of the files?

Comment: And there is `File.Create()` again, which you haven't understood yet. It returns a FileStream that you could use to read from or write to the file, and that needs to be closed or disposed. Don't use it when you don't know what is does.

Comment: @Clemens I want to display a part of the data from those text files I have created, and I AM using the file, it just isn't shown here.

Comment: So you want to read some text from the file and show only that? Or also the file name? Please edit your question and try to be as specific as possible. As you can already see, people are guessing what you are trying to do.

Comment: When you have already found `ComboBox.Items.Add()`, you can simply pass a string to the Add() method, which would automatically be shown in the ComboBox.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. You can try to create a Model for your files, whatever they represent. I'll say `PersonModel` and then try `ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();`

On your PersonModel you'll need properties for whatever information you need to store about a Person like `Name`.

Then write a foreach loop that looks at each item in your directory and creates a PersonModel for each one found, and sets the `Name` property somehow.

Finally at the end, but still inside the loop, do `People.Add(item);`

In Xaml bind the ItemsSource property of your combobox to the People collection. Set DisplayMemberPath of your combobox to `Name`.

Answer (score -1):

As you are in WPF, I would better advise you to use `Binding` for your ComboBox.

Here is a simple way to do it, creating a class ComboItem :

```
public class ComboItem
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }    
}
```

So in your code you just need to do the following :

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboItem> ComboFiles { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ComboItem>();

foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName)) 
{
    ComboFiles.Add(new ComboItem { FileName = file });
}
```

so you can populate your list of ComboBox.
Then in your xaml you can bind to your ObservableCollection like that :

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboFiles}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFile}" DisplayMemberPath="FileName"/>
```

Where SelectedFile is a `ComboItem` Object.

Of course the answer is not "key in hand", but making a bit of research about Binding I am sure you will reach it quickly, I only can advise you that [link](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/#aelm1333)

Comment: @Clemens yes I am aware of it, but it is also written that he uses WPF, and developping in WPF without using Binding is a big shame... I also started like him 2 years ago, and Binding really changed everything for me, that's why I advised him this tutorial, that could be only benefits for him. Then I don't see why you say it wouldn't work(or I missed something?), cause I jsut copied/paste a piece of my code(modified for OP's needs).

Comment: Your `ComboFiles` seems to be a local variable (or a private field). You can't bind to it. It is also totally unclear why there are two properties in your ComboItem class when the most logical approach would be a single property with a sensible name, like e.g, `FileName`.

Comment: @Clemens understand better your answer, in fact I may have put my ViewModel with it. But honestly, if OP doesn't make the tutorial (as the link I wrote), even if I put my ViewModel he would not understand how to use it, just seems he is the same level as I was two years ago, so just going on Stack looking for answers is not enough(mistake I also made in past).

Comment: @Clemens then excuse me but really didn't understand your edit on my answer...

Comment: `ComboFiles` is now a public property that can be used as source of a Binding. The answer is still missing an explanation how an object with that property would be assigned to the DataContext of the view in order to make the Binding work. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @Clemens in fact forgot the "public"... ok so will just edit my answer and add the VM part (but as I wrote earlier, I am sure this will not help if OP doesn't look a bit how MVVM works)

Comment: And you forget the `{ get; }` which makes it a property.

Comment: And for the MVVM part, in my opinion it would be perfectly ok to tell OP to write a single line like `ComboBox.ItemsSource =  Directory.GetFiles(directoryName);`. All the rest is too much for the moment. Assumed that they want to show file names at all. You are just guessing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203547/discussion-between-siegfried-v-and-clemens).